# ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In a nutshell the exception is thrown during POSTing wrapper model and changing the state of one entry to 'Modified'. Before changing the state, the state is set to 'Detached' but calling Attach() does throw the same error. I'm using EF6.

Please find my code below(model names have been changed to make it easier to read)

Model

```
// Wrapper classes
        public class AViewModel
        {
            public A a { get; set; }
            public List<B> b { get; set; }
            public C c { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            if (!canUserAccessA(id.Value))
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

            var aViewModel = new AViewModel();
            aViewModel.A = db.As.Find(id);

            if (aViewModel.Receipt == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            aViewModel.b = db.Bs.Where(x => x.aID == id.Value).ToList();
            aViewModel.Vendor = db.Cs.Where(x => x.cID == aViewModel.a.cID).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(aViewModel);
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(AViewModel aViewModel)
        {
            if (!canUserAccessA(aViewModel.a.aID) || aViewModel.a.UserID != WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name))
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(aViewModel.a).State = EntityState.Modified; //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS BEING THROWN
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(aViewModel);
        }
```

As shown above line

```
db.Entry(aViewModel.a).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

throws exception:

> Attaching an entity of type 'A' failed because another entity of the
>   same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when
>   using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

Does anybody see anything wrong in my code or understand in what circumstances it would throw such error during editing a model?

Comment: Have you tried attaching your entity before setting the `EntityState` ? As your entity comes from a post request, it should not be tracked by the current context, i guess that it considers that you try to add an item with an existing ID

Comment: I have tried this one and the result is exactly the same :( For some reason context thinks Im creating a new item, but Im just updating the existing one...

Comment: I check the state of 'a' before the error is thrown and the state of this object is 'Detached' but calling db.As.Attach(aViewModel.a) throws exactly the same message? Any ideas?

Comment: I just saw your update, how did you setup your context lifetime scope ? Is it per request ? If the `db` instance is the same between your two actions, it can explain your problem, as your item is loaded by the GET method (then tracked by the context), and it may not recognize the one in your POST method as the entity fetched before.

Comment: I think we might be on the write track here but Im not sure how to check my context lifetime scope? Ive got 'protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)' in my controller. Should that be called automatically by MVC after each request?

Comment: It depends, how is declared (and initialized) your `db` context ? Are you using Dependency Injection ?

Comment: db context is created as varible in a aController. Ive just checked it and it is called per request and dispose is called as well.

Comment: Does `canUserAccessA()` load the entity directly or as a relation of another entitiy?

Comment: Clear all State

dbContextGlobalERP.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Problem SOLVED!

`Attach` method could potentially help somebody but it wouldn't help in this situation as the document was already being tracked while being loaded in Edit GET controller function. Attach would throw exactly the same error.

The issue I encounter here was caused by function `canUserAccessA()` which loads the A entity before updating the state of object a. This was screwing up the tracked entity and it was changing state of a object to `Detached`.

The solution was to amend `canUserAccessA()` so that the object I was loading wouldn't be tracked. Function `AsNoTracking()` should be called while querying the context.

```
// User -> Receipt validation
private bool canUserAccessA(int aID)
{
    int userID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
    int aFound = db.Model.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.aID == aID && x.UserID==userID).Count();

    return (aFound > 0); //if aFound > 0, then return true, else return false.
}
```

For some reason I couldnt use `.Find(aID)` with `AsNoTracking()` but it doesn't really matter as I could achieve the same by changing the query.

Hope this will help anybody with similar problem!

Comment: slightly neater and more performant: if (db.As.AsNoTracking().Any(x => x.aID == aID && x.UserID==userID))

Comment: Note: you need `using System.Data.Entity;` to use `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: In my case updating only fields except entity id worked fine:
var entity = context.Find(entity_id);
entity.someProperty = newValue;
context.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.someProperty).IsModified = true;
context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Massive Help.  I added the .AsNoTracking() before my FirstOrDefault() and it worked.

Answer (score 123):

Interestingly:

```
_dbContext.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(entityToBeUpdatedWithId);
```

Or if you still is not generic:

```
_dbContext.Set<UserEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entityToBeUpdatedWithId);
```

seems to solved my problem smoothly.

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfect in my scenario where I was needing to update records in a many to many with a custom join table in a disconnected app.  Even with the entity grabbed from the database, I was getting referential errors, etc.  I was using "context.Entry(score).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;" but this finally worked!  Thank you!!

Comment: This works. All the other suggestions about attaching and using notracking failed as I was already doing noTracking. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This worked for me whilst updating **parent and child** entities within the **same unit of work**. many thanks

Comment: For anyone looking, `AddOrUpdate` is an extension method in the `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` namespace.

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivalent for "DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;" this, like the AddOrUpdate function is for EntityState=Added or EntityState=Deleted ? Your method worked well for Add or Update, but I still receive the OP error in my Delete function.

Comment: @Artyomska Unfortunately I do not know.

Comment: @guneysus, I had same question where your suggestion worked. However, my question is little different. If you can have a look on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681549/entity-framework-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another) would be good.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works and setting the state to modified doesn't?

Comment: Cost me a few hours and in the end this answer was the solution. Still wondering like Jon why this is working and setting the state to modified doesn't

Answer (score 18):

It seems that entity you are trying to modify is not being tracked correctly and therefore is not recognized as edited, but added instead.

Instead of directly setting state, try to do the following:

```
//db.Entry(aViewModel.a).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.As.Attach(aViewModel.a); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Also, I would like to warn you that your code contains potential security vulnerability. If you are using entity directly in your view model, then you risk that somebody could modify contents of entity by adding correctly named fields in submitted form. For example, if user added input box with name "A.FirstName" and the entity contained such field, then the value would be bound to viewmodel and saved to database even if the user would not be allowed to change that in normal operation of application.

**Update:**

To get over security vulnerability mentioned previously, you should never expose your domain model as your viewmodel but use separate viewmodel instead. Then your action would receive viewmodel which you could map back to domain model using some mapping tool like AutoMapper. This would keep you safe from user modifying sensitive data.

Here is extended explanation:

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201303/Blog/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/

Comment: Hi Kaspars, thanks for input. The Attach method throws the same errors as mention in my question. The problem is that canUserAccessA() function loads entity as well as CodeCaster noticed above. But saying that I am very interested in your suggestion wtih regards to security. Could you suggest what should I do to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: Updated my answer with additional info about how to prevent security vulnerability.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
var local = yourDbContext.Set<YourModel>()
                         .Local
                         .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == yourModel.Id);
if (local != null)
{
  yourDbContext.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
yourDbContext.Entry(applicationModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 13):

for me the local copy was the source of the problem.
this solved it

```
var local = context.Set<Contact>().Local.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == contact.ContactId);
                if (local != null)
                {
                    context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }
```

Answer (score 10):

My case was that I did not have direct access to EF context from my MVC app.

So if you are using some kind of repository for entity persistence it could be appropiate to simply detach explicitly loaded entity and then set binded EntityState to Modified.

Sample (abstract) code:

MVC

```
public ActionResult(A a)
{
  A aa = repo.Find(...);
  // some logic
  repo.Detach(aa);
  repo.Update(a);
}
```

Repository

```
void Update(A a)
{
   context.Entry(a).EntityState = EntityState.Modified;
   context.SaveChanges();
}

void Detach(A a)
{
   context.Entry(a).EntityState = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, although i didn't bother using a repository to reference the context entity states.

Answer (score 7):

Use `AsNoTracking()` where you are getting your query.

```
  var result = dbcontext.YourModel.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.aID == aID && x.UserID==userID).Count();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have added this answer only because the problem is explained based on more complex data pattern and I found it hard to understand here.

I created a fairly simple application. This error occurred inside Edit POST action. The action accepted ViewModel as an input parameter. The reason for using the ViewModel was to make some calculation before the record was saved.

Once the action passed through validation such as `if(ModelState.IsValid)`, my wrongdoing was to project values from ViewModel into a completely new instance of Entity. I thought I'd have to create a new instance to store updated data and then saved such instance.

What I had realised later was that I had to read the record from database:

```
Student student = db.Students.Find(s => s.StudentID == ViewModel.StudentID);
```

and updated this object. Everything works now.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd share my experience on this one, even though I feel a bit silly for not realising sooner.

I am using the repository pattern with the repo instances injected into my controllers. The concrete repositories instantiate my ModelContext (DbContext) which lasts the lifetime of the repository, which is `IDisposable` and disposed by the controller.

The issue for me was that I have a modified stamp and row version on my entities, so I was getting them first in order to compare with the inbound headers. Of course, this loaded and tracked the entity that was subsequently being updated.

The fix was simply to change the repository from newing-up a context once in the constructor to having the following methods:

```
    private DbContext GetDbContext()
    {
        return this.GetDbContext(false);
    }


    protected virtual DbContext GetDbContext(bool canUseCachedContext)
    {
        if (_dbContext != null)
        {
            if (canUseCachedContext)
            {
                return _dbContext;
            }
            else
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }

        _dbContext = new ModelContext();

        return _dbContext;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                // Clear down managed resources.

                if (_dbContext != null)
                    _dbContext.Dispose();
            }

            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

This allows the repository methods to re-new their context instance upon each use by calling `GetDbContext`, or use a previous instance if they so desire by specifying true.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with local var and i just detach it like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var old = db.Channel.Find(channel.Id);
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase objFiles = Request.Files[0];
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(objFiles.InputStream))
        {
            channel.GateImage = binaryReader.ReadBytes(objFiles.ContentLength);
        }

    }
    else
        channel.GateImage = old.GateImage;
    var cat = db.Category.Find(CatID);
    if (cat != null)
        channel.Category = cat;
    db.Entry(old).State = EntityState.Detached; // just added this line
    db.Entry(channel).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return View(channel);
```

Problem causes of loaded objects with same Key, so first we will detach that object and do the the updating to avoid conflict between two object with the same Key

Comment: @Artjom B  Problem causes of loaded objects with same Key, so first we will detach that object and do the the updating to avoid conflict between two object with the same Key

Answer (score 2):

i mange to fix the issue by updating state. when you trigger find or any other  query operation on the same record  sate has been updated with modified so we need to set status to Detached then you can fire your update change

```
     ActivityEntity activity = new ActivityEntity();
      activity.name="vv";
    activity.ID = 22 ; //sample id
   var savedActivity = context.Activities.Find(22);

            if (savedActivity!=null)
            {
                context.Entry(savedActivity).State = EntityState.Detached;
                context.SaveChanges();

                activity.age= savedActivity.age;
                activity.marks= savedActivity.marks; 

                context.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return activity.ID;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, after probing for 2-3 days found ".AsNoTracking" should be removed as EF doesn't track the changes and assumes there are no changes unless an object is attached. Also if we don't use .AsNoTracking, EF automatically knows which object to save/update so there is no need to use Attach/Added.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error where

- two methods, A & B, in a single controller both used the same instance of an ApplicationDbContext, **and**
- method A called method B

```
    private ApplicationDbContext db;
    // api methods
    public JsonResult methodA(string id){
        Resource resource = db.Resources.Find(id);
        db.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return methodB()
    }

    public JsonResult methodB(string id){
        Resource resource = db.Resources.Find(id);
        db.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

I changed method B to have a using statement and rely only on the local *db2*.
After:

```
    private ApplicationDbContext db;    
    // api methods    
    public JsonResult methodA(string id){
        Resource resource = db.Resources.Find(id);
        db.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return methodB()
    }

    public JsonResult methodB(string id){
        using (var db2 = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Resource resource = db2.Resources.Find(id);
            db2.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db2.SaveChanges();
        }
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Luke Puplett is saying, the problem can be caused by not properly disposing or creating your context.

In my case, I had a class which accepted a context called `ContextService`:

```
public class ContextService : IDisposable
{
    private Context _context;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
    public ContextService(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
//... do stuff with the context
```

My context service had a function which updates an entity using an instantiated entity object:

```
        public void UpdateEntity(MyEntity myEntity, ICollection<int> ids)
        {
            var item = _context.Entry(myEntity);
            item.State = EntityState.Modified;
            item.Collection(x => x.RelatedEntities).Load();
            myEntity.RelatedEntities.Clear();
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                myEntity.RelatedEntities.Add(_context.RelatedEntities.Find(id));
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

All of this was fine, my controller where I initialized the service was the problem. My controller originally looked like this:

```
    private static NotificationService _service = 
        new NotificationService(new NotificationContext());
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
```

I changed it to this and the error went away:

```
    private static NotificationService _service;
    public TemplateController()
    {
        _service = new NotificationService(new NotificationContext());
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _service.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did in the similar case.

That sitatuation means that same entity has already been existed in the context.So following can help

First check from ChangeTracker if the entity is in the context

```
var trackedEntries=GetContext().ChangeTracker.Entries<YourEntityType>().ToList();

var isAlreadyTracked =
                    trackedEntries.Any(trackedItem => trackedItem.Entity.Id ==myEntityToSave.Id);
```

If it exists

```
  if (isAlreadyTracked)
            {
                myEntityToSave= trackedEntries.First(trackedItem => trackedItem.Entity.Id == myEntityToSave.Id).Entity;
            } 

else
{
//Attach or Modify depending on your needs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with a "using" block

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

    {

       // stuff to do with data base
    }

    // or if you are using entity framework 
    using (DataBaseEntity data = new DataBaseEntity)
{

    }
```

Here is where I get the idea https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/es-ES/b4b350ba-b0d5-464d-8656-8c117d55b2af/problema-al-modificar-en-entity-framework?forum=vcses   is in spanish (look for the second answer)

Comment: just be careful and only use 1 instance of database conexion, specially if you are using entity framework if you don't do it you will get the error Entity Framework An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Answer (score 1):

you can use added method like;

```
_dbContext.Entry(modelclassname).State = EntityState.Added;
```

but in many case if you want to use more than one model at that time this won't work because entity is already attached to another entity. So, at that time you can use ADDOrUpdate Entity Migration method which simply migrates object from one to another and as a result you wouldn't get any error.

```
_dbContext.Set<modelclassname>().AddOrUpdate(yourmodel);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem may also be seen during `ViewModel` to `EntityModel` mapping (by using `AutoMapper`, etc.) and trying to include `context.Entry().State` and `context.SaveChanges()` such a using block as shown below would solve the problem. Please keep in mind that `context.SaveChanges()` method is used two times instead of using just after `if-block` as it must be in using block also.

```
public void Save(YourEntity entity)
{
    if (entity.Id == 0)
    {
        context.YourEntity.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        using (var context = new YourDbContext())
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges(); //Must be in using block
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear all State

dbContextGlobalERP.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);

Answer (score 0):

Reasons I've encountered this error:

1. Did not use `.AsNoTracking()` when querying for existing entities. Especially when calling a helper function to check permissions.
2. Calling `.Include()` on a query and then trying to edit the parent. Example: `var ent = repo.Query<Ent>().Include(e=>e.Ent2).First(); ...repo.Edit(e.Ent2); repo.Edit(e);` If I'm going to edit a nested object, I try to separate these into separate query calls now. If you can't do that, set the child object to null and iterate through lists, detaching objects like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects)
3. Editing an old entity in a `Put` web call. The new item is already added to the repo, so modify that one and have it be saved in `super.Put()`. Example of what will throw an error: `public void Put(key, newItem){ var old = repo.Query<Entity>().Where(e=>Id==key).First(); ... repo.Edit(old); super.Put(key,newItem); ... }`
4. Multiple helper functions edit the same entity. Instead of passing the ID as a parameter into each function, pass a reference to the entity. Error solved!

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I had wrote really two times an entity of same type .   So I delete it and all things work correctly