# Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, primary-key

Let me quickly describe my problem.

I have **5 databases** for 5 customers and **each has the same table called SubnetSettings**.

I already created a dropdownlist to select a customer and will shows up the SubnetSetting table which belong to selected customer and allow me to create, edit and delete.

I can create, delete without problem but **when I want to edit the data it brings the error:**

*Server Error in '/TMS' Application.*

*Attaching an entity of type 'CFS.Domain.Entities.SubnetSettings' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.*

**Here is my Edit in my Controller**

```
    // GET: /SubnetSettings/Edit1/5   
    public ActionResult Edit1(short? id)  
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SubnetSettings subnetsettings = detailView.SubnetSettings.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id); 
        if (subnetsettings == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        } 
        return View(subnetsettings);
    }


    // POST: /SubnetSettings/Edit1/5   
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit1([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,fDialUp,fPulse,fUseExternalGSMModem,fGsmDialUp,bUploadMethodId")] SubnetSettings subnetsettings)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                templateDb2.Save(subnetsettings);   
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        return View(subnetsettings);
    }
```

**Here is the Save method in the EF**

```
     public SubnetSettings Save(SubnetSettings subnetsettings) {

     if (subnetsettings.Id == 0){                        
         context.SubnetSettings.Add(subnetsettings);
     }
     else {

         context.SubnetSettings.Attach(subnetsettings);               
         context.Entry(subnetsettings).State = EntityState.Modified; 
     }
        context.SaveChanges();
        return subnetsettings;
    }
```

I know it's hard to understand other people's code. So any recommend or suggestion is very thankful.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 8):

Synthesizing the answer objectively: 
The object you are trying to update don't came from the base, this is the reason of the error. The object came from the post of the View.

The solution is to retrieve the object from base, this will make Entity Framework know and manage the object in the context. Then you will have to get each value that has changed from View and consist in the object controlled by the Entity.

```
// POST: /SubnetSettings/Edit1/5   
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit1([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,fDialUp,fPulse,fUseExternalGSMModem,fGsmDialUp,bUploadMethodId")] SubnetSettings subnetsettings)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Retrieve from base by id
            SubnetSettings objFromBase = templateDb2.GetById(subnetsettings.Id);

            //This will put all attributes of subnetsettings in objFromBase
            FunctionConsist(objFromBase, subnetsettings)

            templateDb2.Save(objFromBase);   
            //templateDb2.Save(subnetsettings);   

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    return View(subnetsettings);
}
```

Comment: to avoid that annoying message I had to load the record from database in order to use `context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I bounded my ItemsSource to an entity framework model in XAML. I then requested the ItemsSource variable (which is an ObservableCollection) and tried to update that. It resulted in the error above.

Then I tried to set the ItemsSource by code:

ItemsSource = database_context.model.Local

and it solved my problem.

Comment: Once I read this "The object you are trying to update don't came from the base, this is the reason of the error. The object came from the post of the View." it all became clear to me. Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the error I used AutoMapper to copy the view model object into the base object, before Updating.

```
Category categoryFromBase = Repository.GetById(categoryFromViewModel.Id);
Mapper.CreateMap<Category, Category>();

Mapper.Map<Category, Category>(categoryFromViewModel, categoryFromBase);
Repository.Save(categoryFromBase);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the following line is doing what you intend:

```
Mapper.Map<Category, Category>(categoryFromViewModel, categoryFromBase);
```

I think the following is what you want:

```
Category categoryFromBase = Mapper.Map<Category>(categoryFromViewModel)
```