# Edit Account user and role .Net core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, repository, asp.net-core-identity, user-roles

I am using .Net Core Identity 5, I did add Role for the user when registering the account. I want when I Edit the user information of that account, I can change their Role in the system.
I am working in Repo, how can I work with it most effectively?

**Viewmodel**

```
    public class UserRoleViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999926/updating-user-role-using-asp-net-identity) might help ! not sure what exactly are you looking for. I suggest you can once go through the concepts of identity.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't seem to be successful

Comment: Any errors you getting ?

Comment: I have been trying it out since yesterday, I made various changes so I am not sure what the error is.

Comment: I have updated to add a Repo to show my User including Role, how can I get UserRole Id from it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but you can get all users like the following:`var user = await _userManager.Users.Include(x => x.Role).Tolist()`