# Update entity framework error key same value EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, updatemodel

I already make code in c# like this

```
IList<BookViewModel> ListBook= _bookService.GetListById(BookViewModel);
  foreach (BookViewModel apart in ListBook)
    {
    apart.Status = "Published";
    _bookService.Update(apart);
    }
```

and code update in my repository like this.

```
   public virtual TEntity Update(TEntity updatingObject)
        {
            this.GetDbSet<TEntity>().Attach(updatingObject);
            this.SetEntityState(updatingObject, EntityState.Modified);
            this.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            return updatingObject;
        }
```

and my method

```
public IList<BookViewModel> GetListById(BookViewModel bookVM)
        {
            Expression<Func<Book, bool>> criteria = c => c.IdBook == bookVM.Id Book;

            return this.GetList(criteria);
        }
```

but i have error

> Attaching an entity of type 'Models.Book' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already
>        has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state 
>       of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. 
>       This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>        this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state 
>       of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

can any one have suggestion for change code update method, i already read many reference but it's different. thank's!

Comment: What does GetListById look like? Chances are it is loading the entities into the context, therefore attaching them again to the same context will cause an error.

Comment: i already update code for GetListById , and can you more explain what i do for fixed this..

Comment: What happens if you just call SaveChanges without trying to Attach or SetEntityState? If EF already knows about your entity, you should be able to just save it.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this question i have some solution for update entity i use
Entity framework extended.. this already in nugget..

- [Entity framework Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/)