# How to Updating a parent Entity Object only MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to update a parent entity **ONLY** that contains a child entity also preventing child from inserting a new record is null for the child.

But I am receiving the error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

or sometimes complaining that:

> Child entity is null therefore cannot update

Suppose I have:

```
    public void updateParentModel(myModel model)
    {
        mycontext.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        mycontext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I tried this below and it's also not working:

```
    //mycontext.Entry(model).Property(x => x.Serviced).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: Child entity within the model is null, rebind it when updating the parent entity.

Comment: What are the validation errors you are getting? Also, could you provide the code for parent and child entities?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects)

Comment: @SteveGreene i've look into that before coming here.Dettach doesnt allow me to save my parent entity.
@AmanvirSinghMundra no matter what validation errors. i just don want to validate child entity field by field and child by child.
@sajal reason to rebind? when i retrive the parent eitity,the child is already `null` there is nothing for me to rebind or insert or update for the child.