# Child Model Creation Failed when ViewModel have BaseModel property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, automapper, repository-design

I am using WebAPI2 and i have 2 models

```
public class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<Model2> Children{ get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Model1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
}
```

In my view model i am convertinh this to ViewModel using **Automapper**
My CRUD operations of first one is fine as ViewModel also same as Model1.

For my second model (Model2), the following is my ViewModel

```
 public class Model2ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Model1Id { get; set; }

     public string Model1Name { get; internal set; }
     public string Model1Description { get; internal set; }
}
```

My code like below;

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(int model1Id, Model2ViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            model.Model1Id= model1Id;
            var item = Mapper.Map<Model2>(model);

             myRepo.Add(item);
             myRepo.SaveAsync()
            if (!result)
            {
                return BadRequest("Could not Save to the database");
            }

            return Created(uri, Mapper.Map<Model2ViewModel>(item));
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(ex.ParamName, ex.Message);
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

I am using Repository Pattern and the logic in add record is below;

```
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        entity.RecordStatus = DataStatus.Active;
        entity.CreatedDate = entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveAsync()
    {
        int count = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return count > 0;
    }
```

When i use post method of Model2 , i got error like Name is Required of Model1. Why Model1 also trying to create. Please help me

*Note: For simplicity i added my repo calling, directly in the controller code. In real code it calling business method and from there only repo called.*

Comment: Model1 is a child of Model2. If you don't want that added in the same step then either set it's EntityState to unchanged or set the nav to null. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects

Comment: nice i got that. Then i think issue in AutoMapper mapping. While mapping ViewModel to Model, it created Parent object. That is the issue. Any solution to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, tell automapper to ignore it in your mapping config: `.ForMember(dest => dest.Model1, opt => opt.Ignore())`