# Cannot add or update a child row when adding a new row

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects/25441152#25441152) and am using the solution that it is suggesting but still getting the same error.

I have an `Agency` table with a foreign key constraint to `User` Table, this the `Agency` table:

```
CREATE TABLE agency (
    AgencyId                BIGINT          NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserId                  BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    AgencyName              VARCHAR(150)    NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Agency PRIMARY KEY(AgencyId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Agency_User FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES user (UserId) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

This is my `Agency` entity:

```
[Table("agency")]
public class Agency
{
    public long AgencyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; } // <-- user Entity

    [Required]
    [StringLength(GlobalConstants.MaxLengthForLongName)]
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add a new Agency for an existing User:

```
public void AddOrUpdateAsAdminUser(Agency agency)
{
    if (agency.UserContact.UserId <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception($"User: {agency.User.Email} does not exists");
    }

    if (agency.AgencyId > 0)
    {
        // update existing agency
        _context.Agency.Attach(agency);
        _context.Entry(agency).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Entry(agency).Property(x => x.UserId).IsModified = false;
        _context.Entry(agency.User).State = EntityState.Detached; // <-- don't update User
    }
    else
    {
         // add new agency: exception is thrown here
        _context.Agency.Add(agency);
        _context.Entry(agency.User).State = EntityState.Detached; // <-- Don't update User
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`_context.SaveChanges();` line throws the following exception:

> "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (\"dbName\".\"agency\", CONSTRAINT \"FK_Agency_User\" FOREIGN KEY
>   (\"UserId\") REFERENCES \"user\" (\"UserId\"))"
>
> System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}

Comment: you can see the generated query in the logs

Comment: @viveknuna: thanks for your suggestion, the problem was my userId was not being mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to add/update a row to agency that does not have a valid value for the UserID field based on the values currently stored in table1.

Comment: You are right, my userId was not was not being mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my mapping logic, when mapping `AgencyViewModel` to `Agency`, I was only mapping `UserViewModel` to `User`... which means `UserId` was 0 (not mapped) when I wanted to save the agency.

```
[Table("agency")]
public class Agency
{
    public long AgencyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }  // <-- I was NOT mapping UserId

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; } // <-- I was mapping User

    [Required]
    [StringLength(GlobalConstants.MaxLengthForLongName)]
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
}
```