# EF Core duplicate keys: The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, change-tracking

I'm working on a form using EF Core in Blazor Server. I had a number of issues with entity tracking so I set all of my queries to AsNoTracking and designed my service to create a new instance of dbcontext for each query. I think this is appropriate as none of the returned values will be edited - only the form data that users enter and the id references to the queried fields, such as employee numbers, will be stored. For inserting data, I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260049/14024210):

```cs
using var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();
context.SetupForm.Attach(model);
context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I am attaching the data rather than adding it and then setting the form object state to added. This ensures EF Core doesn't attempt to insert the existing employee objects when it inserts the form data.

The trouble starts in a section of the form that can have as many items as the user wants. The select a couple of employees and type in relevant data. When they submit the form, they may have selected the same employee in multiple items. As these employees were selected from separate contexts, they are two separate instances with the same ID. Of course, EF Core doesn't like this and throws errors like this one:

```
The instance of entity type 'Principal' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{EmployeeID: 1234}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

I understand why this error is occurring but I need to be able to attach multiple entities in this way. How can I work around this issue?

One thing I could do is assign the foreign keys manually but that would be rigid and require updates whenever the model changes.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
using var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();

context.Set<Principal>().Add(model);
//or maybe context.Principals.Add(model);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: What exactly is this accomplishing? Isn't Set<Type> the same as using the DbSet of the context for that type?

Comment: I can't see your dbcontext.  I guess you can try context.Principals.Add(model);

Comment: The principals are properties of the main model so i can’t add my model to the dbcontext. If it’s not clear i can clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick! What it does is mark any entity that lacks a key as added. Otherwise, the entity is ignored entirely.

```cs
using var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();
context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(model, node =>
{
     if (!node.Entry.IsKeySet)
     {
          node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
     }
});
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

None of the items that have a key will need to be inserted. Treating them as untracked then solves any issues with duplicates and only inserts the rows that need it.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution#resolve-duplicates