# EFCore update: The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 0}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, change-tracking

This relates to my previous question from a few days ago: [EF Core duplicate keys: The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '' is already being tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67942855/ef-core-duplicate-keys-the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because/67973255#67973255)

I am using `context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` to give me more control when inserting data. The insert process works great as show by my own answer on the question above. This problem results when I update items and attempt to save them.

My primary model is as follows (type names have been changed for simplicity):

```cs
public class Model
{
    public List<Data1> List1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

`Data1` looks like this:

```cs
public class Data1
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

To update to the database, I use this:

```cs
            using var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();
context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(model, node =>
            {
                if (!(node.Entry.Entity.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(EFChangeIgnore)) && node.Entry.IsKeySet)) //this is a workaround but it solves the pk problems I have been having
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else if (!node.Entry.IsKeySet)
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            });
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This works great as it prevents my existing entities (inheriting from`EFChangeIgnore`) from being inserted and otherwise handles updates and inserts of other entities well. However, if I have more than one `Data` item in `List1`, I get the error:

```
The instance of entity type 'Data1' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 0}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

I understand this error but I am confused as to why it is appearing in this scenario. Yes, both entities have an ID of zero, but only because they have yet to be inserted to the database. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Are you sure you want to mess around with `context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph`? What was the reason to use the `TrackGraph()` method? Why not use the normal `Add()`/`Remove()` methods like everyone else?

Comment: If i use add then i get key errors. EF core can’t tell the difference between my existing read only entities that should not be updated and entities that have been edited. I’ll explain more clearly with the example once i put that together.

Comment: I turns out I made a bit of a mistake... See my answer @Progman

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my bug was due to a misplaced parenthesis. Go figure.

In my `SaveChanges` I had accidently negated the entire conditional at the top, such that entities that should have been Modified became Added, and vice versa. This led to multiple entities with an ID of 0 that I intended to add being marked as Modified. EF then complained that two existing entities had the same ID.

That is, this line:

```cs
if (!(node.Entry.Entity.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(EFChangeIgnore)) && node.Entry.IsKeySet))
```

now becomes (conditionals swapped for clarity):

```cs
if (node.Entry.IsKeySet && (!node.Entry.Entity.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(EFChangeIgnore))))
```

And my entire SaveChanges method now is:

```cs
using var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();
            context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(model, node => //all entities inheriting from EFChangeIgnore will not be touched by the change tracker. Other entities with keys will be modified, and items without keys will be added
            {
                if (node.Entry.IsKeySet && (!node.Entry.Entity.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(EFChangeIgnore)))) //this is a workaround but it solves key duplication problems
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else if (!node.Entry.IsKeySet)
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```