# Repository pattern giving exception while updating record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

In my MVC application, I have been using Repository pattern for DAL.

Now, when I do select one entity record and and update the entity field value and do Update operation then getting below error.

> Attaching an entity of type 'DAL.User' failed because another entity
>   of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can
>   happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate."}                System.Exception

Below is repository stuff:

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    if (_context.Entry(entity).State != EntityState.Modified)
    {
         _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Calling as follow:
      In Bussines layer library:
          Manager class :

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private IRepository <User , int> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _unitOfWork.GetRepository<AccountUser, int>();
        }
    }
    public void UpdateUserEntity(UserDTO u)
    {
        try
        {

            User model = new User ();
            UserRepository.Update(Mapper.Map(u, model));
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Please guide me how I could resolve above error.

Comment: Where is the Tentity argument for the Update() method coming from? Is it an object that you read from the database, modified , and are now trying to save back to the database? Or is it an model object that was created by posting data to some web endpoint in your application?

Comment: Please find udated question with manager layer stuff.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 4):

The exception says that there is another entity with the same key that has been attached, but different reference.

- The exception could be caused by previous attached entity.

  ```
  db.Set<Entity>().Attach(new Entity { Id = 123 });
  db.Set<Entity>().Attach(new Entity { Id = 123 }); // different reference but same key
  ```
- Or could be also caused by tracked entity that automatically attached.

  ```
  db.Set<Entity>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 123); // automatically attached
  db.Set<Entity>().Attach(new Entity { Id = 123 }); // different reference but same key
  ```

The second cause can be solved by mentioning `AsNoTracking` when retrieving item.

```
db.Set<Entity>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 123);
```

Or to be safe you can use this extension to always detach any attached entity.

```
public static class DbSetExtension
{
    public static void SafeAttach<T>(
        this DbContext context, 
        T entity, 
        Func<T, object> keyFn) where T : class
    {
        var existing = context.Set<T>().Local
            .FirstOrDefault(x => Equals(keyFn(x), keyFn(entity)));
        if (existing != null)
            context.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Detached;

        context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
db.SafeAttach(entity, e => e.Id);
```

Comment: do you have any comment on even if existing entity's state changed to detached, attaching the new one still throws error.

Comment: AsNoTracking solved my problem. that's really wonderful, i was wondering why when i fetch it from DBContex and modify the object and then attach the modified object, it threw me exception as that was the first time i had attached that entity as per my understanding. But i was wrong and not knowing about the self tracking mechanism of the Entity Framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the reason,
"TEntity entity as a new object instead of the one which already exists".
Means,Entity framework treats each new object as new entry.(eventhough with same existing old data,PK & all).

Solution is,

> First retrieve the object from database
>
> Do/assign the changes to the same object (preferably without changing Primary key)
>
> Then do state as Modified ,Update,SaveChange()

Comment: Its already there as i do first retrieve and then populate on ui and ui will update the values and then calling update method which throws above expceiton. Please check updated quesiton with manage layer stuff.