# How to iterate user list, change a variable, and save to database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm new to Identity, EF6, and SQL databases. Please bear with me.

The idea is this: For each user in the database, change a user variable, and save that user. However, I must be going about it incorrectly, as I trip an InvalidOperationException (the infamous: **Attaching an entity of type 'Models.ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.**)

```
var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

IQueryable<ApplicationUser> query = _db.Users; // from IdentityDbContext

// search for matching user
List<ApplicationUser> subordinates = query.Where(p => (p.ParentId == userEmployeeId)).ToList();

if (subordinates != null)
{
  foreach (var sub in subordinates)
  {
    sub.Nickname = "Scooby"; // change an example test variable

    IdentityResult result = manager.Update(sub); // EXCEPTION here! Boom.
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("User did not save");
    }
  }
}
```

Q: What am I doing wrong here? Or, how should I attack this differently?

Comment: what does the manager.update do?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `manager` is an instance of the ASP.NET Identity UserManager, the error is because `Update()` is trying to add the entity to the context when it was already added to the context when it was queried.

There are a couple ways to solve this. One is to update the user directly using EF (note that this bypasses any logic that would've been applied if saved via UserManager)...

```
foreach (var sub in subordinates)
{
    sub.Nickname = "Scooby"; // change an example test variable
}
_db.SaveChanges();
```

The other option is to use `AsNoTracking()` to prevent it from being added to the context during the query. After that, `manager.Update(sub)` should work...

```
List<ApplicationUser> subordinates = query.AsNoTracking()
                                       .Where(p => (p.ParentId == userEmployeeId))
                                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. Using the manager.Update() is using a different context (behind the scenes) than the _db. So, calling manager.Update() wasn't what I needed -- it was _db.SaveChanges();