# MVC Issue updating table (viewModel) mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting the following error message when I try to update my data back to the table:

Attaching an entity of type 'Namespace.Models.Child' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.

Like usual I am guessing it is something simple but I am not sure where the issue is.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ParentsCreateVM viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var parent = new Parent()
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName,
                ParentID = viewModel.ParentID
            };

            //db.Parents.Add(parent);
            db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)
            {

                var child = new Child()
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    DOB = item.DOB,
                    Address = item.Address,
                    ParentID = viewModel.ParentID,
                    ChildID = item.ChildID

                };

                 db.Entry(child).State = child.ChildID == 0 ?
                               EntityState.Added :
                               EntityState.Modified; 

            }



            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, but from your previous questions, `Child` has a property `ParentID` which you are not setting

Comment: I just added ParentID to the Child in the Edit() Post. I still get the same error. If I can get this to work I will have my CRUD working for all my viewModels.

Comment: Are you editing an existing child or adding a new one?

Comment: Editing an existing. Actually, even if I do not edit one, when I submit my edit form I get this error.

Comment: Then you will also need to set the `ChildID` property (if your doing `db.Childs.Add(child);` in a loop, you keep adding `Childs` whose `ChildID` will be `zero`. Note you can also get the original from the database and just update its properties from the view model

Comment: I'm probably confused here, but I'm not inserting I am updating. db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Yes, but the `ChildID` property of each child your updating has `ChildID=0`

Comment: even you mention db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified; but db.Childs.Add(child) mean you add new record, when you add new records, if same key's constraint will give you errors. your EntityState level have to go down one more level, mean every records in the Child model have to tell their own State.

Comment: @Stephen, I ran the debugger and you are right ChildID is 0 as well as ParentID is 0 for all children.  Also the Parent class in the debugger show Childs = null. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you rendering a control in the view for `ChildID`? And you should set the `ParentID` from the parent, not the child - i.e. `ParentID = viewModel.ParentID` (the `ChildVM` property does not need to include a property for `ParentID`)

Comment: I forgot to mention, the code above is the latest, so yes I have the ParentID = viewModel.ParentID in the parent. I also have it in the child but regardless if it is there or not it does not work. What do you mean rendering a control for ChildID? I am using an editor template if that is what you mean.

Comment: No, I mean in `foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)` it should be `ParentID = viewModel.ParentID` (no need to duplicate controls for `ParentID` in both the `ParentVM` and again in the `ChildVM`. Does you `EditorTemplate` for `ChildVM` include `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ChildID)`?

Comment: This indicates that your context lives too long, not one context per request.

Comment: @Gert, I am not sure I follow you?

Comment: @Stephen, that solved my issue. I added the ParentID = viewModel.ParentID like you requested and I removed the comments from the @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ChildID) in the Editor Template and I am now in business. Thanks so much. Please post answer so I can give you credit for.

Comment: You have edited you question with the correct code, so giving you an answer wont make much sense now :)

Comment: Ooops, my bad. :-(   Well, I will know for next time not to modify the answer and follow the proper procedure. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 0):

Exception is clear, dbcontext already has load the same child item.

I suggest you do this way

```
//find child item in db
var child = db.Entry<Child>().Single(child=>child.key== value);
//then chang value
child.Name = item.Name;
child.DOB = item.DOB;
child.Address = item.Address;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Stephen answer was what I was looking for.