# Attaching an entity of type 'EntityType' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have lately updated from `EntityFramework` 4.3.1 (with `Self Tracking`) to `EntityFramework` 6.1.2 (without `Detect Changes`). Due to having an `MVC` client with complex entity tree views, and some other technological choices (like using `SQL Server`'s `RowVersion`) I work in front of the database in detached mode. I have a new instance of the `DbContext` with every request, and I mark the context's state for each entity.

It works just fine. Insert is working on the complete entity tree. Update is working on the type being handled. On `EntityFramework` 4 I had to null all navigation properties to have that flow working. Now I don't seem to have to do that.

BUT, I do get the above exception in the following scenario:

> 1. I have a parent entity node, say *Person*, that has been modified;
> 2. it contains more than one child entity node of the same type, say *Phones*, which are new entries, and thus their identity values are identical (0 for new);

Setting the state of the *Person*'s entry to modified causes the exception, although I would expect `EntityFramework` to not try to handle new (added) child entities' state. I can see when I have only one new phone under the modified *Person*, that the state of the *Phone* entry goes from detached to unchanged.

Do I need to do something so `EntityFramework` knows to handle only the parent entity without its navigation properties on modifications? Or must I resolve to nulling all navigations as I did before?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).