# Saving objects to database with Entity Framework 6 using Attach/Modified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am having an issue saving my objects with entity framework. I am using Webforms and here is how my code is setup:

My `AppSettings` has an `AddressId`. I prefer to save them separately. So `AppSettings` get saved by `AppSettingRepo` and the `Address` gets saved by `AddressRepo`.

CODEBEHIND:

```
    AppSetting appSettings = AdminService.GetAppSettings();
    //SET APP SETTING PROPERTIES

    Address address = AdminService.GetAddressById(appSettings.AddressId);
    //SET APP SETTING ADDRESS PROPERTIES

    AdminService.SaveAppSettings(appSettings);
    AdminService.SaveAddress(address);
```

`AppSetting` Repository(my `AddressRepository` looks exactly the same):

```
    public static void Save(Data.AppSetting appSettings)
    {
        using (var context = new AppContext())
        {
            if (appSettings.Id == 0)
            {
                context.AppSettings.Add(appSettings);
            }
            else
            {
                context.AppSettings.Attach(appSettings);
                context.Entry(appSettings).State = EntityState.Modified;
                appSettings.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

THE ERROR:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type
>   'App.Data.AppSetting' failed because another entity of the same type
>   already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the
>   'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I was using AutoMapper and mapping in the wrong direction.

No need for both the Attach and setting the State.

**When creating:**
context.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Added;

**When updating:**
context.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Modified;