# How to update one entity if another is in use in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am facing one issue while updating entity with some of the fields updating from original entity. Code is like below

```
 public int SaveUser(UserDetail objUserDet)
    {
     DBEntities context = new DBEntities();
     UserDetail userDetail = (from u in context.UserDetails.Where(u => u.UserDetID == objUserDet.UserDetID)
                                         select u).Single();
     objUserDet.UserId = userDetail.UserId;
     //context.UserDetails.ApplyCurrentValues(objUserDet); //For ObjectContext works fine.
     context.UserDetails.Attach(objUserDet);
     context.Entry(objUserDet).State = EntityState.Modified;
     context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But it gives me an error like

**Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.**

How to update one entity with another is present with same primary key.

Comment: this is not correct use of attach method, I think you meant to use update method.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that the error is due to having two attached objects in the in-memory context with the same primary key. So, you should either:

1. NOT select `userDetail`, or
2. NOT attach `objUserDet` and transfer the changed values to the `userDetail` object instead.

You might also be able to detach the `userDetail` object before `SaveChanges`.