# MVC one-to-many database not updated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have added an `ApplicationCompany` class to my MVC project like this:

```
public class ApplicationCompany
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public ApplicationCompany()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

In the `ApplicationUser` class I have added:

```
public virtual ApplicationCompany Company { get; set; }
```

Now, when I debug an instance of `ApplicationUser`, I can see it has the `Company` property, and I can see the `ApplicationCompany` table in my database. When a user registers, I'd like to add a `Company` linked to them. I am doing the following but it is not saving the company:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationManager
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email
        };

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var company = new ApplicationCompany();
            user.Company = company;
            context.SaveChanges();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure `result.Succeeded` is coming back as true, Can you put visual studio breakpoints and see whether code in your if block is executing. Your code looks fine to me

Comment: Yep, the result is succeeding and i'm hitting the point where I create a new company. context.SaveChanges() comes back with 0 though, as in there are 0 fields in the database to change.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbContext` instance you use into the `if (result.Succeeded)` block doesn't know anything about the `user` instance you just set before calling `context.SaveChanges()`. Modify your code by attaching `user` instance into the context or just changing the state of the `user` to `EntityState.Modified`.

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var company = new ApplicationCompany();
    user.Company = company;
    context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit 1:**

> Attaching an entity of type 'ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Because another context own the user instance, then you must instantiate the `DbContext` into the `if` block (don't forget to suppress the root instance you create at the start of your method) like this:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var company = new ApplicationCompany();
        user.Company = company;
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Added;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: Overriding `CreateAsync` method in `ApplicationUserManager` class**

The better approcach, IMHO, is to oveeride `CreateAsync` method in `ApplicationUserManager` class. by doing that you don't need to add the company updates into your controller's action.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    // ...

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        var company = new ApplicationCompany();
        user.Company = company;
        return await base.CreateAsync(user, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the look of this but it give me the following error: Attaching an entity of type 'ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

Comment: I added a best approach to use for that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks! Very thorough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you are using a different DbContext object to insert the User than the one you are using to insert the company. You should be using the same DbContext object.

Change your `UserManager.CreateAsync` method to accept the DbContext object and use it there to add the new user

```
public Task<SomeDTO> CreateAsync(ApplicationDbContext db, ApplicationUser user,
                                                                         string password)
{
  //to do  : Set the password

  //Use db to add the new User
  db.ApplicationUsers.Add(user);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  // to do  : return something
}
```

And when you call it from your action method, make sure to pass the DbContext.

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(context,user, model.Password);
```

That should fix your problem.