# Generic UnitofWork & Repository pattern with AutoMapper throwing exception "another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm using the following GitHub project for generic repository and UoW pattern

https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("update")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Update(HttpRequestMessage request, ComponentViewModel component)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
            else
            {
                var componentDb = UnitOfWork.Repository<Component>().Find(component.ID);

                if (componentDb == null)
                    response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid component.");
                else
                {
                    componentDb = Mapper.Map<ComponentViewModel, Component>(component);
                    UnitOfWork.Repository<Component>().Update(componentDb); // <-- ERROR'S HERE

                    UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
                    response = request.CreateResponse<ComponentViewModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, component);
                }
            }

            return response;
        });
    }
```

I get the following exception at `UnitOfWork.Repository<Component>().Update(componentDb);`

> Attaching an entity of type 'Component' failed because another entity
>   of the same type already has the same primary key value

I believe it is due to the AutoMapper Mapper.Map code before it, but, I'm not sure how to correct that.

Please advise how to correct the usage.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using `Find` method. This method is going to attach the returned entity to your context, later using Automapper you are creating a disconnected POCO entity, which you are trying later to attach to your context with `Update` method of your generic repository, and both entities share the same `Id`.
Use `Any` extension method instead of `Find` to check if there is an entity with that `Id` in your table:

```
 if (UnitOfWork.Repository<Component>().Any(c=>c.Id==component.ID))// Call Any here
 {
       componentDb = Mapper.Map<ComponentViewModel, Component>(component);
       UnitOfWork.Repository<Component>().Update(componentDb); 
       UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
       response = request.CreateResponse<ComponentViewModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, component);
 }
 else
 {
      response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid component.");
 }
```