# Entity Framework and DBContext attach action

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have two simple DB Tables:

Persons (id, name, house)

Houses (id, street, city)

The 'house' column of the Persons table is the foreign key to specify in which house a person lives. Easy example.
I created a model from the Database and now I am trying to learn how to work with the EF. 
I am for instance trying to attach a disconnected entity to an existing context:

```
    House dh = new House() { city = "Seattle", street = "St Road 1" };
    dh.Persons = new List<Person>();
    dh.Persons.Add(new Person { namen = "Andrew" });
    dh.Persons.Add(new Person { namen = "Thorsten" });

    YardEntities cx = new YardEntities();
    cx.Houses.Attach(dh);
```

The last line throws an Exception I do not understand:

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type
>   'DataAccessLayer.Person' failed because another entity of the same
>   type already has the same primary key value.

Why is that? Andy ideas? The primary key 'id' has an auto increment and is the primary key of my tables.

Edit:

Code of my two entity classes:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string namen { get; set; }
    public int house { get; set; }

    public virtual House House1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class House
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public House()
    {
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Share the code of the classes `Person` and `House`. It seems that `Id` is not set to `autoincrement`. When you don't define it in the instanciation, the Id property take the default value of ite type (0 for `int`). Here, your 2 persons have the same `Id`.

Comment: I only set the autoincrement in the database. The code for my two entities is generated by the model generator:

Comment: So the column is `IDENTITY` on the 2 tables ?

Comment: Yes my tables both have the IDENTITY flag in id. But in the generated code I cannot see anything regarding this.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I suggest you to test the second solution for `DatabaseFirst` context.

It seems to be a problem whit the definiton of the `Primary Key` and Entity Framework.

To have this problem of `duplicate key`, it's because it is no defined as `identity` (autoincrement) => your code shows that you don't define the `Id` when you add new `Person` or a `House`.

For `DatabaseFirst` context, you have the choice of solutions:

- You modify your table to make the `Id` column `Identity`.
- You define the `Id` property like this:

  ```
  House dh = new House() { Id = 1, city = "Seattle", street = "St Road 1" };
  dh.Persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, namen = "Andrew" });
  dh.Persons.Add(new Person { Id = 2, namen = "Thorsten" });
  ```

For `CodeFirst` context, you have this 2 solutions:

- `CodeFluent` solution:

  ```
  modelBuilder
      .Entity<Person>()
      .Property(f => f.Id)
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
  ```
- `DataAttribute` solution:

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      public long Id{ get; set; }

      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: But if I use "add" instead of "attach" everything works fine. I thought, that the only difference between attach and add is that the state is not set to "added" automatically. But I cannot even set the state if I am not allowed to attach my disconnected type first.

Comment: And how should I always know the next key? Your code shows, that I should specify the ID with 1, but it might be another one the next time.

Comment: You can't directly, except making a query tatht takes the `Max` id from the table. I think you should always use `Add` to ensure your objects have the correct state flag.

Comment: Yes, that would be my solution too. But then I absolutely do not understand the purpose of "Attach".