# C# MVC CMS - Customising Remote Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, remote-validation

At the link below I asked a question about how to ensure a field does not already contain the same value (for example when there is a unique constraint on a field which correctly causes C# to throw an exception when voilated). With the answer I received, it solved that problem but presented another.

[Ensuring another record does not already contain the same value for a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260932/ensuring-a-field-does-not-already-contain-the-same-value/39261258#39261258)

The main issue I now have is that when I create a new View. The validation works as expected. In brief - The system needs to check that the ViewName and ViewPath (route) are both unique so a search of the DB is required.

However, when I edit the view, the validation kicks in again (and it actually should not because obviously the view exists already because you are editing it).

My issue now is how do I customise the remote validation to work differently for edit vs create. While we should not be able to edit the name of a view to match an existing view, we should also not be stopped from saving the current view simply because it is the same as the current view.

Below is my Model (the part that is not (hopefully) generated by a tool :-):

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IViewMetaData))]
public partial class View : IViewMetaData { }

public interface IViewMetaData
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DALResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorRequiredField")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DALResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorLessThanCharacters")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(DALResources), Name = "ViewName")]
    [Remote("IsViewNameAvailable", "Validation")]
    string ViewName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DALResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorRequiredField")]
    [StringLength(400, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DALResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorLessThanCharacters")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(DALResources), Name = "ViewPath")]
    [Remote("IsViewPathAvailable", "Validation")]
    string ViewPath { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(DALResources), Name = "ViewContent")]
    string ViewContent { get; set; }
}
```

The part I am having a problem with is the [Remote] validation attribute which is defined below:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    private FRCMSV1Entities db = new FRCMSV1Entities();

    public JsonResult IsViewNameAvailable(View view)
    {
        bool isViewNameInvalid = db.View.Any(v => v.ViewName == view.ViewName && v.Id != view.Id);

        if (!isViewNameInvalid)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        string suggestedViewName = string.Format(UI_Prototype_MVC_Resources.ErrorViewAlreadyExists, view.ViewName);

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string altViewName = view.ViewName + i.ToString();
            bool doesAltViewNameExist = db.View.Any(v => v.ViewName == altViewName);
            if (!doesAltViewNameExist)
            {
                suggestedViewName = string.Format(UI_Prototype_MVC_Resources.ErrorViewNotAvailableTry, view.ViewName, altViewName);
                break;
            }
        }
        return Json(suggestedViewName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult IsViewPathAvailable(View view)
    {
        bool doesViewPathExist = db.View.Any(v => v.ViewPath == view.ViewPath && v.Id != view.Id);

        if (!doesViewPathExist)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        string suggestedViewPath = string.Format(UI_Prototype_MVC_Resources.ErrorViewAlreadyExists, view.ViewPath);

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string altViewPath = view.ViewPath + i.ToString();
            bool doesAltViewPathExist = db.View.Any(v => v.ViewPath == altViewPath);
            if (!doesAltViewPathExist)
            {
                suggestedViewPath = string.Format(UI_Prototype_MVC_Resources.ErrorViewNotAvailableTry, view.ViewPath, altViewPath);
                break;
            }
        }
        return Json(suggestedViewPath, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the validation needs to work the same on both create and edit. It just needs to do an additional check on edit to ensure we are still referring to the same record and if so, then there is no need to show the validation message because there is nothing wrong.

My question is:
1. How do I get this to work as expected.
2. I can see that both methods are pretty much identical, which violates the DRY principle. How can I make this more generic and simplify it. However the first question is really the one I would like answered because there is no point in refactoring something that doesn't work.

For more information, the above code is also an edit of the code at the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to pass the ID property of the model as `AdditionalFields`. Assuming its `int Id`, then

```
[Remote("IsViewPathAvailable", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
public string ViewName { get; set; }
```

and the the method should be

```
public JsonResult IsViewNameAvailable(string viewName, int? id)
```

Note that in the `Edit` view, you include a hidden input for the `Id` property, so its value will be posted back by the jquery.validate remote function.

You can then check if the `id` parameter is `null` (i.e. it's new) or has a value (it's existing) and adjust the queries to suit.

```
bool isViewNameInvalid;
if (id.HasValue)
{
    isViewNameInvalid = db.View.Any(v => v.ViewName == viewName && v.Id != id);
}
else
{
    isViewNameInvalid = db.View.Any(v => v.ViewName == ViewName);
}
```

What is currently happening is that the `Remote` is only posting the value of the `ViewName` property, and because your parameter is the model, it is initialized with the default `id` value (`0`) and your query is translated to `Any(v => v.ViewName == viewName && v.Id != 0);`

I also recommend using a view model rather that your `partial class`

Side note: from the code that generates `suggestedViewName`, your expecting a lot of `ViewName` with the same value, meaning your possibly making numerous database calls inside you `for` loop. You could consider using linq `.StartsWith()` query to get all the records that start with your `ViewName` value, and then check the in-memory set in your loop.

Comment: Your answer worked. Thanks again for your help. I'll address each of your suggestions in separate comments. The suggestions to use Remote has really cut down the code in the controllers. The only thing I don't like is that this is a validation concern but it is setup as a controller. I might try to find an alternative way to do this and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: ViewModels. I will indeed use a ViewModel but I am just prototyping this at the moment and want to see if I can get a functional system from it. Later I will separate it into layers and do all that good stuff and this is when the ViewModels will really become essential. However, I do agree, they should be used.

Comment: .StartsWith() - This was a great suggestion. I just implemented it now. Thanks again for all your help Stephen.