# How to delete detached entities when they share the same foreign keys but different object instances?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to delete a list of detached entities. The entities to be deleted have relationships to other entities (foreign keys), for example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int BarId {get;set;}
    public virtual Bar Bar {get;set;}
}
```

In some cases, 2 Foo entities might have the same Bar id. However, because these are detached entities and not being tracked by the context, the 2 Foo entities have 2 unique Bar entities.

To delete Foo I'm doing (in a generic repository class):

```
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dataContext.GetEntry(entity);

    if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    else
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

This works for the first Foo entity only. For other Foo entities where Bar is the same, I get the exception:

> Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

As a work around, I'm setting `Foo.Bar = null` before calling `Delete()`. This works fine.

However, is there a better way to delete multiple entities from the context?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting state without attaching, like:

```
dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

What you are doing, is that you are check if state of entity has not already been set to `Deleted` then set its state to `Deleted`. This is fine, but if state of entity has already been set to `Deleted`, you are trying to attach and remove. It is unnecessary. If entity state is `Deleted` it measn that it is not `Detached`, there is no need to re-attach and re-delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete an entity you can use direct SQL statement, like this

```
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from YOURTABLE where id=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", entity.id));
```