# Primary key violation even if attached - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, exception, primary-key

In a car sharing application a user can offer a ride and then each ride contains a list of bookings.

But when I try to add a reservation it does not work, even if the customer (which is already added) is attached...

**The exception is :**

> Attaching an entity of type **'CARS_Models.Models.Member'** failed because
>       another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.
>       This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>       entity to **'Unchanged'** or **'Modified'** if any entities in the graph have
>       conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have
>       not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the **'Add'**
>       method or the **'Added'** entity state to track the graph and then set
>       the state of non-new entities to **'Unchanged'** or **'Modified'** as appropriate.

**The method is :**

```
public void AddBooking(Booking b)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataContext(Settings.Default.db))
    {
        ctx.Members.Attach(b.Customer);
        ctx.Ride.Attach(b.Ride);

        ctx.Bookings.Add(b);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Everything else I did in this project works fine except this. I don't understand why this doesn't work as well.. I also tried to "Attach" after "Adding" but it doesn't work either.

**Classes attributes :**

```
public class Ride
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Member Driver { get; set; }
    public int TotalSeats { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public String Departure { get; set; }
    public String Arrival { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } = new List<Bookings>();
}

public class Member
{
    public string Login { get; set; } //This is the PK
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Ride> Rides { get; set; } = new List<Ride>(); //Rides that this member will drive.
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } = new List<Reservation>(); //All the bookings he made (for others ride).
}

public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Member Customer { get; set; } //The member who paid.
    public int Seats { get; set; } //Because someone can book more than 1 seat.
    public Ride Ride { get; set; } //The ride it concerns.
}
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent)
this Might help

Comment: Most likely `b.Customer` and `b.Ride.Driver` are different `Member` instances with the same PK `Login`.

Comment: Oh yes, for the test I made them the same, do you think it's the problem ? I'll try with different members...

Comment: Omg... That was the problem... I dont know how you guessed it but thank you :D... Very impressive :p...