# Entity Framework: Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I found multiple posts for this issue, however my issue is little different and error shown is exactly matches to my scenario.

1. I have two different schema under by database. e.g. `PreSchool.Students` & `School.Students`. And per our requirements, rest is same for both `Students` tables, including primary key.
2. Now in my code, I am updating record of 'PreSchool.Students' using following code:

   ```
   var wouldBeUpdatedStudent = await context.Students
               .FindAsync(student.StudentIdentity).ConfigureAwait(false);
   wouldBeUpdatedStudent = student; //updated student object
   context.Entry(wouldBeUpdatedStudent).State = EntityState.Modified; // This line throws error 
   var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```
3. Under `OnModelCreating` I clearly set `tableName` & `SchemaName` for each of Entity. By this, I am expecting whenever I change entity/ model state, it should catch the correct table as per setting done under `OnModelCreating`. However this is not happening and throws exception.

> I tried using `context.Students.AsNoTracking()` this works if no cascading to Students Entity. However, there are some cascading/children entities which are also same DDL. e.g. `context.Student.Exams`

Comment: I asked a very similar question a couple years ago.  Back then the answer was "Entity Framework doesn't support tables of the same name in different schemas in Sql Server."

Comment: @SamAxe, fortunately, I tried [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771363/659538) and worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically I didn't get answer which gives proper explanation -fix on this error. However [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771363/659538) resolved my issue. One more think I observed with is solution is, if new object has exactly same values as per entity underlying database, it won't update table.

e.g.

```
context.Set<Student>().AddOrUpdate(wouldBeUpdatedStudent);
result = await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

> Reason I cannot use `AsNoTracking()` because I have nested entities which are same across other schema. So Even if I use `AsNoTracking()` at top level entity, I get same error for child level. **Same as I mentioned in my question.**