# The instance of entity type 'XY' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'XId', 'YId'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Sorry to raise this one again - I see it plenty of times on here but I am still puzzled about it in my case, especially because I seem to be able to 'overcome' it, but I'm not sure I like how, and I would love to understand why.

I have a many to many relationship between Staff and Departments, with the StaffDepartment table being set up with a composite key like so:

`modelBuilder.Entity<StaffDepartment>()
                .HasKey(sd => new { sd.StaffId, sd.DepartmentId });`

I suspect that must be something to do with the exception I sometimes get:

`InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'StaffDepartment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'StaffId', 'DepartmentId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

I say sometimes because, strangely, if I change the department in my staff details page and update, it goes through fine, but when I leave it the same  (maybe just changing the staff name for example) I receive this exception.

I tried implementing the various suggestions on this 
[similar but apparently different SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent?rq=1)
and all sorts of ways of tinkering with my repository update method, and strangely enough this is the only way I have got it working:

```
public async Task UpdateStaff(StaffDto staff)
        {
            var staffToUpdate = await _db.Staff
                .Include(d => d.Departments)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.Department)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == staff.Id);

            // Without either these two line I get the exception
              _db.StaffDepartment.RemoveRange(staffToUpdate.Departments);
              await _db.SaveChangesAsync();               

            _mapper.Map(staff, staffToUpdate);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

So it seems strange that I should have to call `SaveChangesAsync()` twice in same method. What is actually happening there? And how would I achieve the suggestion in the error `When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached` without doing so.

Entity classes look like so:

```
public class Staff
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
        public ICollection<StaffDepartment> Departments { get; set; }
    }

public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        ...
        public ICollection<StaffDepartment> Staff { get; set; }
    }

public class StaffDepartment
    {
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public Staff Staff { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

    }
```

And the staffDto that comes back from the domain etc. is simply:

```
public class StaffDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
        public List<DepartmentDto> Departments { get; set; }
    }
```

The repositories are all registered as transient i.e.

```
services.AddTransient<ICPDRepository, CPDRepository>();
```

Comment: What is happening here is that `_mapper.Map` cannot be used for applying disconnected entity graph changes. It needs more intelligent processing - like [Detached.EntityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#detachedentityframework) or [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

Comment: @IvanStoev Ah, thanks, I shall have to look into that.
But how am I ending up with "another instance with the same key value for {'StaffId', 'DepartmentId'}"?
And why does it work if the department is changed?

Comment: The thing is, when you call `_db.StaffDepartment.RemoveRange(staffToUpdate.Departments)`, the entity **instances** you've removed are still tracked by the context (with state `Deleted`). So anytime you try to add new entity **instance** of the same type and with the same PK, you get such exception. After calling `SaveChanges`, the `Deleted` instances are removed (no more tracked). The problem with AM `Map` is that it creates **new instances** with the same PK. This is what AM.Collection is trying to address.

Comment: I see. Thing is, I only added `_db.StaffDepartment.RemoveRange(staffToUpdate.Departments)` in one of my many attempts get over the exception. Couldn't I avoid this step entirely if the departments remained the same? Or is it the general practice to remove the many-to-many collection and add afresh, be it the same or otherwise?

Comment: The best approach is to detect the added/deleted entries.