# Should I use AsNoTracking when returning only a single record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc and recently I came across a method called AsNoTracking(). I did some research and found out that AsNoTracking() helps to speed up performance. It should be used with queries in which we do not want to save the data back to the database. So I know that AsNoTracking() helps to boost performance if you are returning hundreds to thousands of records. However, What I was wondering is that What if you are only returning **one** record?. For example the record of a specific employee. Is there a need to use AsNoTracking()?

Comment: The answer is "it depends", which makes this an opinion based question I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG Oh I see, because I was wondering why no one talks about this situation haha

Comment: `AsNoTracking()` isn't meant to speed up performance. It's meant to disable change tracking when you don't intend to edit the entities you load. Hence, you *do* need it if you intend to load even that single entity and save it back using the same context

Comment: Honestly though, I think you really don't have to worry about this unless you're running a high volume website.

Comment: @Issaki people do talk about it. You have to understand what it does though and why you need it, not blindly turn it on or off. Read-only, use `AsNoTracking()` even for a "single" entity.  Edit in the same context, don't. In a web application, it depends - the context used in a `Get` action won't be the same as the one used in a `Post`.

Comment: @Issaki in a Get, where nothing is ever saved to the database you don't need change tracking. In a Post, you do.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay! Thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its will be useful to know that where AsNoTracking() could be needful.

In certain scenario where you post an Edit call and before actually updating the model to database you are trying to check if particular record already exists or not and then you want to place Update call it will throw exception. Below is the demonstration of such scenario.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    var modelFromDb = db.Model.Where(x => x.ID == model.ID);

    if (modelFromDb.Count() > 0)
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified; //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR WILL BE THROWN AS RECORD WITH ID IS ALREADY ATTACHED WITH modelFromDb OBJECT.
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

You will find many questions asking about error like "Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value" which can be caused by above snippet.

AsNoTracking() can prevent such exceptions. Suggested code will be like below.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    var modelFromDb = db.Model.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ID == model.ID);

    if (modelFromDb.Count() > 0)
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified; //WORKS PERFECTLY.
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

You can refer one such question asked here [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent)